# Watir-webdriver: can't start new session for IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

How can I start absolutely new session for IE browser?

I use the following code:

```
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie    
  @browser.cookies.clear 
  @browser.goto "http://..."
```

but when I run tests, I'm always seeing that IE browser starts with logged in user that was used for the previous test.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountered the same problem, and I solve it by configuring Internet Explorer options. 
You should check the box "Delete history when you quit the browser".

There is a consequence : you can't do parallel tests.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will delete history, but not cookies :(